# Getting url by ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have problem getting my url in Ajax

my html

```
<input type="text" class="proId" value="{{$order->id}}">
```

my js:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#pay-button').click(function (event) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
          });
        event.preventDefault();
        // $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var proId = document.getElementsByClassName('proId').value;
            $.ajax({
              url: '{{url('orderspayonline')}}/'+encodeURI(proId),
              type: "POST",
              cache: false,

              success: function(data) {
                var resultType = document.getElementById('result-type');
                var resultData = document.getElementById('result-data');

                function changeResult(type,data){
                  $("#result-type").val(type);
                  $("#result-data").val(JSON.stringify(data));
                }

//rest of it...
              }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I get `404` `undefined` in network as result, I suppose to get `http://domain/orderspayonline/id`

I need to use `document.getElementsByClassName` (getting class) instead of id because i have more than 1 row in my table.

Comment: The variable `proId` is a node list. I don't believe that will work in your ajax URL. Try logging the url string to the console to see what it looks like.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Try that way:

```
$.ajax({
  type    : 'POST', 
  url     : "{{ route('route-name', ['param' => $param]) }}",
  data    : formData, 
  dataType: 'POST'
})
```

Comment: look now, with param

Answer (score 0):

Update in your js file

```
url: '{{url("orderspayonline")}}/'+encodeURI(proId),
```

Use double quotes inside. Using single quotes inside terminates the string.

Comment: only gets first row id

Comment: see i have table and each row `<tr>` is covered with this form the button suppose to work for all rows not only first one, any idea?

Comment: it is, value="{{$order->id}}"

Comment: @mafortis As I said in my comment on your post, if you use classes then the `proId` will be a node list (an object). You therefore can't get the `.value` property of it as it will return `undefined`.

Comment: Use  $('#pay-button{{$order->id}}').click(function (event) { ... } and also change in id attribute in your html..

Comment: @AdamJB I changed proId to something random, no luck.

Comment: In your html id="pay-button{{$order->id}}" and in your js $('#pay-button{{$order->id}}').click(function (event) { ... }. Write both the codes inside the loop.

Comment: @SunnyKumar  `$('#pay-button{{$order->id}}').click(function (event) {
    $.ajaxSetup({........` and `<button class="btn btn-block btn-theme02" id="pay-button{{$order->id}}" type="submit">Pay!</button>` not working :\